# Flutter – how to format phone number text field

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, phone-number

I want to make  my `TextFormField` formats input number in proper phone number format.

I'm have tried using below `TextInputFormatter`

```
class NumberTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    final int newTextLength = newValue.text.length;
    int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;
    int usedSubstringIndex = 0;
    final StringBuffer newText = new StringBuffer();
    if (newTextLength >= 1) {
      newText.write('+');
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 1) selectionIndex++;
    }
    if (newTextLength >= 3) {
      newText.write(newValue.text.substring(0, usedSubstringIndex = 1) + ' ');
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 2) selectionIndex += 1;
    }
    if (newTextLength >= 3) {
      newText.write( ' ');
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 6) selectionIndex += 1;
    }
    if (newTextLength >= usedSubstringIndex)
      newText.write(newValue.text.substring(usedSubstringIndex));
    return new TextEditingValue(
      text: newText.toString(),
      selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
    );
  }
}
```

but i'm not getting expected output

My expected number format  **`"+1 123-456-7890"`**

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure there are must be two fields - one for country prefix and another one for home number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have decided take phone number and country code from two separate `TextFormField`

> **`CountryCodeTextInputFormatter`** for output like this **`+12`**

```
class CountryCodeTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    final int newTextLength = newValue.text.length;
    int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;
    int usedSubstringIndex = 0;
    final StringBuffer newText = new StringBuffer();
    if (newTextLength >= 1) {
      newText.write('+');
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 1) selectionIndex++;
    }
    if (newTextLength >= usedSubstringIndex)
      newText.write(newValue.text.substring(usedSubstringIndex));
    return new TextEditingValue(
      text: newText.toString(),
      selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
    );
  }
}
```

> **`PhoneNumberTextInputFormatter`** for output like this **`132-456-7890`**

```
class PhoneNumberTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    final int newTextLength = newValue.text.length;
    int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;
    int usedSubstringIndex = 0;
    final StringBuffer newText = new StringBuffer();
    if (newTextLength >= 4) {
      newText.write(newValue.text.substring(0, usedSubstringIndex = 3) + '-');
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 3)
        selectionIndex += 2;
    }
    if (newTextLength >= 7) {
      newText.write(newValue.text.substring(3, usedSubstringIndex = 6) + '-');
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 6)
        selectionIndex++;
    }
    if (newTextLength >= 11) {
      newText.write(newValue.text.substring(6, usedSubstringIndex = 10) );
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 10)
        selectionIndex++;
    }
    if (newTextLength >= usedSubstringIndex)
      newText.write(newValue.text.substring(usedSubstringIndex));
    return new TextEditingValue(
      text: newText.toString(),
      selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newText.length),
    );
  }
}
```